# How to display uploaded csv file data using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Currently I am doing a project in php for uploading CSV file and to insert data into database.
Before inserting the data I need to display the data in table format.

I used this code for uploading and inserting the data.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$name = $_POST['camname'];
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
}

Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    $import="INSERT into uploadmail(name,email) values('$name','$data[0]')";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
}

fclose($handle);
}
```

This coding successfully inserts the data into database but I need to display the data in table format.so please give any suggestions.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: I suspect this previously asked question has your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your code with this. Data will be save to DB and will be display as well.
I added display data in table format code in your code.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$name = $_POST['camname'];
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) 
{
    echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
}

Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
echo "<table>\n<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $import="INSERT into uploadmail(name,email) values('$name','$data[0]')";

    echo "<td>".$name."</td><td>".$data[0]."</td>";
    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "\n</table>";
fclose($handle);
}
```