# How to change one particular column's background color when importing data from a CSV

Tags: php, html, html-table, import-from-csv

I am importing CSV data into a HTML table using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page) solution. Right now the table has 7 columns (but the number of rows will vary from 20-60 time to time). My client asked me to change the 5th column's background color to something else so that one particular column stands out from the rest. How can I do that?

My code:

```
 <?php
 $f = fopen("so-csv.csv", "r");
 while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
       echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
 }
 fclose($f);
 ?>
```

**UPDATE**

Thank you **roullie** & **Ghost** for your quick responses! However, I forgot to mention that my client wants the table to have 2 colors, e.g. if all the columns are red, only the 5th one will be gray. So I had...

```
foreach ($line as $cell) {
  echo '<td style="background-color: #892525;">' . htmlspecialchars($cell) . '</td>';
}
```

Now how can I add your solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a key checking while inside the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($line as $k => $cell) {
   // index starts at zero
   $color = ($k == 4) ? '#ccc;' : '#892525;';
   $class = "style='background-color: $color'";
   echo "<td $class>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: @AlwaysANovice you mean like this? if column == 5 -> gray, else -> red?

Comment: this is so confusing, after I replaced my `foreach` with your's, I am getting a 500 error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` :( any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @AlwaysANovice change this line, there is a typo: `$color = ($k == 4) ? '#ccc;' : '#892525;';`

Comment: @AlwaysANovice yeah take that rest. glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
 $five = 5;
 $ctr = 1;
 $f = fopen("so-csv.csv", "r");
 while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($line as $cell) {
       echo "<td ".($ctr==$five?"style='background:red":"").">" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
    $ctr++;
 }
 fclose($f);
 ?>
```