# to retrieve data from excel sheet to a web page

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to retrieve or get data that is stored in the excel file back on the web page that is stored earlier or present earlier in the excel sheet.

Comment: You've flagged this as `phpexcel`, have you actually looked at the [PHPExcel library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)?

Comment: You can use PHPExcel to fetch data from an Excel spreadsheet. Then, print it out however you like. You can use PHPExcel to create Excel spreadsheets as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically display a CSV file as an HTML table on a web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page)

Comment: No a little knowledge of php excel used it to transfer data from web page to a excel file sheet.

Comment: But want the vice versa of it i.e to fetch data from excel and display it on the web page.

Comment: Read the PHPExcel documents, look at the examples.... load your Excel file and use the HTML Writer to generate web page markup.... it takes about 8 lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Read the PHPExcel documents, look at the examples.... load your Excel file and use the HTML Writer to generate web page markup.... it takes about 8 lines of code

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';

$fileType = 'Excel5';
$fileName = 'testFile.xls';

// Read the file
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileName);

// Write the file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```