# automatically build a table in html based on a csv file + can't get possible solution to work

Tags: php, html, csv

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page#comment45922146_518923)

but I cannot get it to work, but it is probably something basic, Can anyone advise?

this is what the php looks like on my server:

```
$ cat table.php
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
 = fopen("temp.csv", "r");
while (( = fgetcsv()) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ( as ) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars() . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose();
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

this is what the csv file looks like:

```
$ cat temp.csv
DeviceName,counter1,counter2,counter3,counter4
DeviceName1,85%,87%,75%,63%
DeviceName2,85%,85%,74%,70%
DeviceName3,80%,81%,70%,66%
DeviceName4,78%,82%,70%,74%
DeviceName5,77%,75%,68%,58%
DeviceName6,77%,72%,66%,58%
```

then I go to the address in the browser

`webaddressgoeshere/php/table.php`

I get the following on my console:

```
GET webaddressgoeshere/php/table.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
Navigated to webaddressgoeshere/php/table.php
```

my answer below, i was missing a variable when I copeid and pasted. oops!!

```
$ cat table.php
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("temp.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: You should delete this question and update your previous question.

Comment: you seem to be missing a couple of variables in the code

Comment: @DNT Tks, I wee the variable i was missing!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($csv_fp = fopen('csv_file.csv','r'))
{
    echo '<table>';
    while ($data = fGetCsv ($csv_fp, 8096, ","))
    {
        // you can view the array $data holds by print_r($data); exit();
       echo '<tr>';
       foreach($data as $d)
       {
            echo '<td>'.$d.'</td>';
       }
    echo '</tr>';
    }
   echo '</table>';
}
else
{
   echo 'Failed to open file';
}
```

Comment: You should write what you have changed so the OP knows for future reference.

Comment: tks, added this `<?php` to the start and saved as a `.php` file but nothing is showing.

Comment: you will of course need to add your own column names etc .. see the next edit and run it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your code have some syntax issues.  The code is incomplete.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";  
$xfile = fopen("temp.csv", "r");  // variable was missing
while (( $line = fgetcsv($xfile)) !== false) {   // here too
         echo "<tr>";
         foreach ( $line as $ value) {   // and here
                 echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($value) . "</td>";    // and here
         }
         echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($xfile);   // and here
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I thought it was missing `?>` at the end but that did not seem to help me.

Comment: Closing PHP block is optional; not closing can have benefits.