# Dynamic tables & boxes

Tags: javascript, dynamic, import-from-csv

I'm creating a view wherein I need to add multiple boxes, wherein there is a number within the box, which is dynamically changing as per data (csv file)

Also, I'm adding tables, with dynamic numbers within the same which should again, change with the data (csv)

I'm trying to design an approach to get it done and looking for js libraries to use here.

Is there anything in particular that I should look for? Can tables be added without table command in html (alternatives)?
Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog post](http://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823) is a simple representation of d3.js usage to load a csv to a html table.

Also there is already a StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page) about loading csv data via php, if you are going for a backend approach.

Comment: Yeah, table is loaded onto csv, but I meant creating new tables which will have dynamic numbers based on the content of csv. 

Also, any ideas on boxes and dynamic numbers within them?