# CSV File to Separate HTML Tables Based on Column Values

Tags: php, html, csv

I have a csv file that is converted to an html table by php (with help from Joby Joseph here): [Dynamically display a CSV file as an HTML table on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page)

However, I would like to put the data into separate tables and container divs based on the values in the first two columns. So if this is my csv data:

```
League,Team,Date,Opponent,Result
american,MIN,May 3,UTA,W
american,MIN,May 4,SEA,L
american,SAC,May 3,DAL,L
american,SAC,May 4,TOR,W
national,NYN,May 5,BAL,L
national,NYN,May 7,MIA,W
national,DET,May 6,DEN,L
national,DET,May 7,POR,L
```

There would be four tables created (MIN, SAC, NYN, and DET), and they would be put into container divs that I have already created, "american-container" for the first two and "national-container" for the second two. Ideally, each table would have two header rows--the team name and the column labels--and the date/opponent/result data. Following is Joby's solution that puts the csv into one table:

```
function jj_readcsv($filename, $header=false) {
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
echo '<table>';
//display header row if true
if ($header) {
    $csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle);
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($csvcontents as $headercolumn) {
        echo "<th>$headercolumn</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
// displaying contents
while ($csvcontents = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($csvcontents as $column) {
        echo "<td>$column</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
fclose($handle);
}
jj_readcsv('test.csv',true);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: don't forget to mark my answer as solved if the problem is solved sir :)

Comment: Of course, but I'm still trying to figure part of it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work :

```
<?php
$csv = "League,Team,Date,Opponent,Result\namerican,MIN,May 3,UTA,W\namerican,MIN,May 4,SEA,L\namerican,SAC,May 3,DAL,L\namerican,SAC,May 4,TOR,W\nnational,NYN,May 5,BAL,L\nnational,NYN,May 7,MIA,W\nnational,DET,May 6,DEN,L\nnational,DET,May 7,POR,L";
$csv_array = explode("\n", $csv);
$tables = [];
foreach($csv_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    $line = explode(',', $value);
    if (array_key_exists($line[1], $tables)) {
        $tables[$line[1]][] = $line;
    } else {
        $tables[$line[1]] = [$line];
    }
}

foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
    echo '<h1> ' .$key. ' </h1>'; // YOUR TITLE (Team)
    echo "<table>";
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach (explode(',', $csv_array[0]) as $keyHeader => $valueHeader) {
        if (in_array($keyHeader, [0, 1])) {
            continue;
        }
        echo "<th>$valueHeader</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    foreach ($value as $keyRow => $valueRow) {
        echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($valueRow as $keyValue => $valueValue) {
                if (in_array($keyValue, [0, 1])) {
                    continue;
                }
                echo "<td>$valueValue</td>";
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Here is what i get :
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bxkhs89k/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sofiene, but the first two columns shouldn't be part of the table data. The first column is for saying what div to put it in, while the second is a header row above the column labels, like so: `NYN<br />Date Opponent Result<br>May 5 BAL L`

Comment: @Beau i updated the code ;), i put the league in an H1 above the table :)

Comment: There's one other thing I can't figure out, Sofiene: how do you put the first column (american or national) into a table class (I have a jquery funtion to then append it to its matching div)? I know the info is in $tables[$line[0]], but I don't know how to get it into the table tag. Thanks.