# Proper displaying of csv file data in table if some fields are empty

Tags: php, csv, html-table

I want to display a .csv file neatly in a table using php. Some content of the file are empty field.

Here is my first approach, got an error but displaying the datas in one row. Supposedly they should display in their respectively fields.

The code output here: 
[image]

Should be like this:

[image]

```
<table border = "1">
        <tr>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>        
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Datepaid</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
          $data = file("data/payment.csv");
          foreach ($data as $line){
          $lineofarray = explode("\t", $line);
          list($name, $email, $address, $payment, $datepaid) = $lineofarray;//error here
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?= $name?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $email?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $address?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?= $payment?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <?= $datepaid?>
            </td>


        </tr>
        <? }?>
</table>
```

My code now had an error on the part of list. And displaying the datas in one field. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this.

```
$fp = fopen("data/payment.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $field) {
                echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($field) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

This is a safe way to read csv lines as it is unicode safe and also supports fields that are wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: even when some fields are empty? does it display neatly?

Comment: Yes it will. Please try it.

Comment: Another thing, In the future I will using this(datas) to compare on other csv file. If the date and payment amount are match to the other csv file it will be mark as MATCHED. So the easy access of each data by row here is obsolete.

Comment: Comparing csv lines like that is dangerous. What if the two csv lines had exact same data but the formatting was different? Say one had fields wrapped in double quotes while the other didn't?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way from your code that the displaying of data would be like this? <td><?= $name?></td>
<td><?= $email?></td>
<td><?= $address?></td>
<td><?= $payment?></td>
<td><?= $datepaid?></td>

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fgetcsv`:

```
$fp = @fopen('data/payment.csv', 'r');
$tbl = '<table><thead><tr><th>NAME</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th><th>Payment</th><th>Datepaid</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
while($r = fgetcsv($fp)){
  $tbl .= '<tr>';
  foreach($r as $v){
    $tbl .= '<td>'.htmlentities($v, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').'</td>';
  }
  $tbl .= '</tr>';
}
$tbl .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $tbl; // echo $tbl wherever you want
```

Comment: Thanks for help @PHPglue.