# PHP - Add newline to table cell with multiple lines

Tags: php, html, csv, html-table, newline

I am having trouble creating a new line in a HTML table cell. The data is coming from a CSV file and each cell has multiple lines. I tried using `'\n'`, `'\r'`but it's not working. I searched the forums but haven't found a solution. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Should I use a different function? Thanks..

The CSV Looks like this:

```
header,header,header,header,header
,,,,"title 
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc","title 
ddddddd"
```

The code I am using outputs the file like this:

```
       header                 header
title aaaaaaa bbbbbbb      title ddddddd
ccccccc
```

I want it to output like this:

```
 header    header
 title     title
aaaaaaa   ddddddd
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
```

The code I am using is from this thread: [Dynamically display a CSV file as an HTML table on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page)

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("my.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f, 0)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo  "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

I ended up using nl2br. Working code below.

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("my.csv", "r");
while (($line = fgetcsv($f, 0)) !== false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo  nl2br("<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "\n" . "</td>");
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}
fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: This worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the predefined constant `PHP_EOL`, which is «the correct 'End Of Line'» following the php docs.

In fact, "\n" is a typical **unix** end of line, and most windows don't well understand it. Php will take care of that with `PHP_EOL`.

```
echo "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
```

You can also try to use **heredoc** (EOF)

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc