# Need help to fetch data from .csv to html page using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv

I have created a form in PHP where i am inserting data and saving in .csv file now i want to show .csv data into HTML page using page but i don't know how to do. 
this is my form code in PHP.

```
<?php
$error = '';
$name = '';
$email = '';
$number = '';
$gender = '';
$country = '';
$birthdate='';
$address = '';
$education = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 if(empty($_POST["name"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Name</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $name = clean_text($_POST["name"]);
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Only letters and white space allowed</label></p>';
  }
 }
 if(empty($_POST["email"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter your Email</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $email = clean_text($_POST["email"]);
  if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
   $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Invalid email format</label></p>';
  }
 }
 if(empty($_POST["number"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Number is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $number = clean_text($_POST["number"]);
 }
 if(empty($_POST["gender"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Gender is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $gender = clean_text($_POST["gender"]);
 }
 if(empty($_POST["country"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Country is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $country = clean_text($_POST["country"]);
 }
 if(empty($_POST["birthdate"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Date of birth is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $birthdate = clean_text($_POST["birthdate"]);
 }
 if(empty($_POST["address"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Address is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $address = clean_text($_POST["address"]);
 }
 if(empty($_POST["education"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Educational Background is required</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $education = implode(' ',$_POST['education'] );
  // $education = clean_text($_POST["education"]);
 }

 if($error == '')
 {
  $file_open = fopen("test.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("test.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
  $form_data = array(
   'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
   'name'  => $name,
   'email'  => $email,
   'number' => $number,
   'gender' => $gender,
   'country' => $country,
   'birthdate' => $birthdate,
   'address' => $address,
   'education' => $education
  );
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);

  header('location:index_load.php');
 }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <br />
   <div class="col-md-6" style="margin:0 auto; float:none;">
    <form method="post">
     <h3 align="center">Please fill the Form</h3>
     <br />
     <?php echo $error; ?>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Mobile Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter number" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $number ?>"/><br>


     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Gender:</label>&nbsp&nbsp
      <span>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/>
        <label class="choice">Male</label>&nbsp
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/>
        <label class="choice">Female</label>
      </span>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country">Country:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
      </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Date of birth:</label>
        <input type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" value="<?php echo $birthdate ?>">
      </div>

     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Address:</label>
      <textarea name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter address"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Education Background:</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="education[]" value="10th">10th<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="education[]" value="12th">12th<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="education[]" value="B.COM">B.COM<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="education[]" value="B.A">B.A<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="education[]" value="BSC">BSC


    </div>
     <div class="form-group" align="center">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
      <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
     </div>
     </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The above code is storing the data in .csv format now i want to show .csv file data into the html page using php. Can anyone help me how to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically display a CSV file as an HTML table on a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518795/dynamically-display-a-csv-file-as-an-html-table-on-a-web-page)

Comment: @ArSeN Ohhh Yesss, Thank you so much.